# Necessary and Sufficient condition for commuting with a set of commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ \mathcal{M} = \{M_1, \ldots M_d \}$ be a set of countably many mutually commuting $n\times n$ matrices - i.e. $[M_i, M_j] =0$ for all $i,j \in \{1,\ldots, d\}$ - and $A$ be some $n\times n$ matrix. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for A to commute with the set $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: It depends strongly on the elements of $\mathcal{M}$.